# Split columns to rows based off a string

Tags: r, regex, string, strsplit

I have three columns that have multiple values but contain different strings thereafter. These values occur after an ";" but the strings are different. I want to be able to take the following column and turn it into two. There can be more than two values as well, I just used two for this example.

I have this in a row;

```
Cola <- c("Qxxxx7; Pxxxx8")
Colb <- c("Qxxxx7 [1-24]; Pxxxx8 [1-24]")
Colc <- c("Qxxxx7 1xAcetyl [N-Term]; 1xPhospho [S4(100)]; Pxxxx8 1xAcetyl [N-Term]; 1xPhospho [S10(100)]")
```

I need them to separated to 2 rows.

- Row 1:

```
Cola <- c("Qxxxx7")
Colb <- c("Qxxxx7 [1-24]")
Colc <- c("Qxxxx7 1xAcetyl [N-Term]; 1xPhospho [S4(100)]")
```

- Row 2

```
Cola <- c("Pxxxx8")
Colb <- c("Pxxxx8 [1-24]")
Colc <- c("Pxxxx8 1xAcetyl [N-Term]; 1xPhospho [S10(100)]")
```

Comment: You want to further split entries in `colc` or not? Row 1's `c("Qxxxx7 1xAcetyl [N-Term]; 1xPhospho [S4(100)]")` to `c("Qxxxx7 1xAcetyl [N-Term])` and `c(1xPhospho [S4(100)]")`. If yes, how do you want to handle the corresponding `Col a` and `Colb` entries? fill `NA` for them?

Comment: Thanks, I do not want to further split. Essentially the key is in Col a (sorry for typo should be Cola). I just want everything after Qxxxx7 up to Pxxxx8 in row 1 and vice versa. Hope that makes sense?

Comment: something like `library(tidyverse); map_df(transpose(str_split(c(Cola=Cola, Colb = Colb, Colc=colc), "; (?=Pxx)")), list2DF)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```r
do.call(cbind, sapply(df1, function(x) strsplit(x, split = "; (?=Pxx)", perl = T)))
#>      Cola        Colb               Colc                                               
#> [1,] "Qxxxx7" "Qxxxx7 [1-24]" "Qxxxx7 1xAcetyl [N-Term]; 1xPhospho [S4(100)]" 
#> [2,] "Pxxxx8" "Pxxxx8 [1-24]" "Pxxxx8 1xAcetyl [N-Term]; 1xPhospho [S10(100)]"
```

If you have other columns, `tidyr::separate_rows` makes it much easier:

```
library(tidyr)

df1 %>% separate_rows(Cola, Colb, Colc, sep = "; (?=Pxx)")
```

<sup>Created on 2023-12-06 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

#### Data:

```
Cola  <- c("Qxxxx7; Pxxxx8")
Colb  <- c("Qxxxx7 [1-24]; Pxxxx8 [1-24]")
Colc  <- c("Qxxxx7 1xAcetyl [N-Term]; 1xPhospho [S4(100)]; Pxxxx8 1xAcetyl [N-Term]; 1xPhospho [S10(100)]")

df1 <- data.frame(Cola , Colb, Colc)
```